# How to execute command on computer whose name is stored in variable?

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$ADForest = Get-ADForest
$ADForestGlobalCatalogs = $ADForest.GlobalCatalogs
$domain= $ADForestGlobalCatalogs | Select-Object -first 1
//connect with $domain the rest of the code has to be executed on $domain
//rest of code goes here (one out of several different scripts). 
Remove-Mailbox "$A" -confirm:$false
Get-Addresslist | where {$_.Name -like "$k*"} | Update-Addresslist
Get-GlobalAddresslist | where {$_.Name -like "$k*"} | Update-GlobalAddresslist
```

Now I would like to execute a the rest of the code on the computer stored in the variable `$domain`. Does anybody know how to do this? Note that the rest of the code can be one of over a dozen different script so I'm fine with giving the chosen script as a variable and then executing them remotely. Ideally the code would also pass on the arguments automatically so as to now to have to chance the code we have so far.

Edit:

> Invoke-Command [[-ComputerName] <String[]>] [-ScriptBlock] <ScriptBlock> [-ApplicationName <String>] [-ArgumentList <Object[]>] [-AsJob] [-Authentication <AuthenticationMechanism>] [-CertificateThumbprint <String>] [-ConfigurationName <String>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-EnableNetworkAccess] [-HideComputerName] [-InDisconnectedSession] [-InputObject <PSObject>] [-JobName <String>] [-Port <Int32>] [-SessionName <String[]>] [-SessionOption <PSSessionOption>] [-ThrottleLimit <Int32>] [-UseSSL] [ <CommonParameters>]

looks quite good, but I would have to use it with the first argument being `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $domain` ScriptBlock being the rest of the code? How does that work?

Alternively maybe the `Enter-PSSession` command might work?

Comment: Why the close vote? Care to comment?

Comment: I didn't cloes vote, but it is for "Unclear what you are asking", and in fact it is somewhat hard to understand. Did you try [Invoke-Command](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849719.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) ?

Comment: Invoke command looks quite good, reading what it does now and hopefully I can understand it well enough to use.

Comment: I hope this is clearer, now to see if there is a way not to have to change the arguments of my script and how to actually store the code I already have inside the Invoke-command

Comment: Have you looked at `Invoke-Command` examples. I'm sure you would find plenty of running commands on remote machines. Is there something specific you have tried you need help with? Right now it just seems like you want us to post some examples.

Comment: Script block is just a piece of code wrapped in braces, e.g. `$ScriptBlock = { Write-Host "Hello world!" }`. Yes, it can contain multiple lines of code. Note that for `Invoke-Command` to work remotely you need to configure WinRM service on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to something like this:

```
$ADForest = Get-ADForest
$ADForestGlobalCatalogs = $ADForest.GlobalCatalogs
$domain = $ADForestGlobalCatalogs | Select-Object -first 1

Invoke-Command -Computer $domain -ScriptBlock {
  Param(
    [string]$Mailbox,
    [string]$Name
  )

  Remove-Mailbox $Mailbox -confirm:$false
  Get-Addresslist | where {$_.Name -like "$Name*"} | Update-Addresslist
  Get-GlobalAddresslist | where {$_.Name -like "$Name*"} | Update-GlobalAddresslist
} -ArgumentList $A, $k
```

A scriptblock is a piece of code in curly brackets. Scriptblocks normally can't use variables from the surrounding script, though, so you need to pass them into the scriptblock via the `-ArgumentList` parameter.